# Looking for a way to call pacman and make via MINGW64 in C#

Tags: c#, bash, mingw-w64, msys2

So, I am working on a utility to create a GUI for cloning, updating, and ultimately compiling a GitHub project. I have already created a script which does the same general thing via an MSYS2 terminal directly, but I am having trouble getting those same type of commands to work in a C# GUI. I have had luck calling that same script from within the GUI at the click of a button, but I would like to be able to package everything as a standalone executable rather than have to bundle it with a script, though I will if that's what it comes down to in the end.

Here's what I have now (with some if statements removed for controlling additional arguments):

```
ProcessStartInfo compileStart = new ProcessStartInfo();
compileStart.FileName = this.textMSYS2.Text + "\\usr\\bin\\mintty.exe";
this.outputText.Text += "Configuring MSYS2 process...\n";

compileStart.Arguments += "-h always /bin/env MSYSTEM=MINGW64 /bin/bash -l ";

compile.StartInfo = compileStart;
compile.Start();
compile.WaitForExit();
```

As it currently stands, it fails if I add either `pacman` or `make` calls or even a simple `dir` call. The errors returned look like this:

```
/usr/bin/make: /usr/bin/make: cannot execute binary file
/bin/env: Exit 126.
```

If however I make it a call to my `./install.sh` script, the script executes without a problem and the MINGW64 window even remains open after it is done. Any insight as to how I can get this to work without having to package a script with it as well would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing a `-c` alongside `-l` there.  Bash has three modes of operation (maybe more, but that's irrelevant at the moment):

- `-i`: interactive; accepts individual commands supplied through standard input
- `-c FOO`: run command `FOO`
- `foo.sh`: interpret a shell script `foo.sh`

In your case, you're supplying commands, but Bash is trying to interpret them as names of shell script files.

Comment: This was it.

Had to add some additional things over time like `&&` to string together some of the commands I was needing to (i.e. `cd`) in one window, but this gets me very close to a working standalone executable. Just have to work in some additional logic outside this scope specifically, but it's close.

Thanks!